# ctags for c project with emacs and cygwin

Tags: c, emacs, cygwin, ctags

I am trying to understand a c source code, and I am using emacs on cygwin. when I search , I came up with ctags.  I tried to fellow its instruction to how to use it with emacs and cygwin, but i could not fallow it.

I am new at all those things.
could anyone explain a very simple usage of ctags with Emacs and cygwin to find some definition in c Source code.

a step by step example is needed, Thank you in advance

Comment: If there's no restriction on the system, you'd spend a lot less time installing
linux (~30min) than the *overhead* of learning to code under cygwin.

Comment: but, I have to stick to current sytsem, cygwin on windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick start:

**Start by letting CTAGS scan your code.**

From a command prompt, do the following

1. Go to the root directory of your tree
2. Execute `ctags -e -R *` to scan all the code in your tree and generate the 'TAGS' file

   - `-e` says to generate Emacs compatible output
   - `-R` says to recurse directories
   - `*` says to scan everything

**Using TAGS in Emacs**

For all of these, if you are prompted 'Visit tags table', reply with the location of the TAGS file you created above.

- **To find a tag:** press `<M-.>`  You will be prompted for the tag to 
  find.
- **To list tags matching a pattern (apropos)** press `<M-x>tags-apropos<ret>` and provide the regexp of what you are looking for.
- **To search for all occurrances of a tag in every file** press `<M-x>tags-search<ret>` and provide the name of the tag.

*Notes:*

- `<M-x>` means to press the meta key (Alt on a PC) while pressing lowercase x.  (Uppercase does something else.)
- `<M-.>` means to press the meta key (Alt on a PC) while pressing the period.
- `<ret>` means to press the return (or Enter) key

*Example In Emacs*

Let's say I am trying to figure out what the variable that holds the current date is defined.  I remember it has "date" as part of it, but I don't know the entire name.  To do this, I will start by finding the proper name of the variable by using the tags-apropos command to look for all tags that have 'date' in them.  So I type to following:

```
<M-x>tags-apropos<ret>date<ret>
```

I now get a list of every tag that contains date.  In that, I find a tag called 'currentDate'.  Now I need to find where that is defined, so I type

```
<M-.>currentDate<ret>
```

Cool, I found it.  But I still want to find everywhere it is used in the code.  That can be done using the tags-search:

```
<M-x>tags-search<ret>currentDate<ret>
```

Emacs now starts searching through the files.  When it finds the first occurrence of 'currentDate' and highlights it for me.  To move to the next occurrence, I press `<M-,>`.

**Further Info**

For more info on using Tags in Emacs, you may want to see the [Tags section of the GNU Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I was looking for, explained many things clearly. I was always have problem with those commands, now I know how it works.

Comment: <M-x>tags-apropos<ret>  in this command, what is apropos? this command means Press Metakay meanwhile x and input the string you want to find: string-apropos, then click Enter. am I right?  I did that, but nothing responded

Comment: @alim 'apropos' means to look for words containing the pattern you specify.  I've added a short example of the different commands work together along with a pointer to other documentation on tags.

Comment: Hi jwernerny, Thank you for everything. Now I got everything I need, thanks